# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity...How can I add a working button?

Tags: android

```
  @Override 
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {     

      super.onAttach(activity);        
      ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached( getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));            

       Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)   

   }
```

How can I fix this?
I do not know why or how this problem is occurring

Comment: Please post the entire file, there is not enough code here to understand the problem. If I had to guess, you have a static inner class (that extends Fragment) and it thinks you are trying to call the outer Activity class' `findViewById` method. You should wait until `onCreateView()` to make this call, and you should use `view.findViewById()`, where `view` is the inflated layout for the entire fragment.

Comment: okay. when i use view.findViewById, it underlines view and says "view cannot be resolved" There are various quick fixes available